# Brave shows margin on div even with margin set to 0, where as firefox works as intended

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, brave-browser

There is margin on the right on div element even though I set the margin: 0, It works as expected in Firefox. **What is wrong with chrome?**

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/space-goblin/pen/QWmPOQp)

```
<section>
    <h2>CSS Positing Property</h2>
    <div className="css-box illustration">
        <div className="box">
        <div className="box2"><p>box 2</p></div>
        <div className="box1"><p>box 1</p></div>            
    </div>
</section>
```

```
css-box {
    margin: 0;
}

.css-box .box {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}
.box div {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.box2 {
    background-color: red;
}

.box1 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[image]
There is no margin on div.box in Firefox

[image]
There is margin on the right in div.box in Chrome

[image]
The margin is set to zero but chrome has margin on the right where as Firefox doesn't

*I set the margin to 0, which works in firefox but not on brave*

Comment: Did you set `.css-box`'s padding 0? It may cause this problem..

Comment: Chromium is showing you the used margin. Firefox is not. The used margin is the same in both, it's just that only Chromium depicts it.

Comment: @Phillip padding 0 didn't change anything, The problem is with the margin

Comment: @Alohci
what do you mean by used margin?
The div element has a fixed width and height with margin set to 0
which should show a box with no margins like it's showing in Firefox, 
but the div extends to the right on chromium which is not supposed to happen

Comment: @aalizwel23 [Used Values](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-5/#used-value) - the div width is over-constrained, so the used value is different from the specified and computed value.

Comment: @Alohci The used value is the same in both cases which is margin: 0;
Try running this codepen in both the browser and see the difference

https://codepen.io/space-goblin/pen/QWmPOQp